# How to validate 3 or more fields when creating content in D7

Tags: entities

I have a custom content type with 3 fields (integer). How can I check when content is created or edited that the sum of those three fields are equal to a predefined total. For instance, if the three fields represent percentages of a task to be completed, I would like to issue an error message if the sum of the three fields is not 100%

Answer (score 0):

Create a module to add a validation handler to the form by implementing [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7):

```
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'MY_FORM_ID') {
    $form['#validate'][] = '_MODULE_validate';
  }
}
```

Then define the handler function that checks the field values:

```
function _MODULE_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  // Check that the sum of the fields equals a predefined total
}
```

If you're not familiar with creating your own modules, but are comfortable with PHP, you could probably use the [Field Validation](http://drupal.org/project/field_validation) module to add a custom PHP validator that does the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have written modules in the past, so that's not a problem. Just needed that hint.